# How to flatten nest array of different objects but only get value from existing property name?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I wonder how to flatten nested array of different objects & get only existing value from existing property name (of any object)?

I only want to get all of propertyId values only from nest array of 2 different objects.

```
export interface LeftMenuItem {
    text: string;
    routerUrl?: string;
    isExpanded: boolean;  
    propertyId?: string;
    children: LeftMenuChildrenItem[];
}
export interface LeftMenuChildrenItem {
    text: string;
    routerUrl?. string;
    propertyId?: string;
    isCustomer: boolean
}

const leftMenuPropertyIds: string[] = [];

this.leftMenuItems.forEach(val1 => {
    if (val1.propertyId) {
        leftMenuPropertyIds.push(val1.propertyId);
    }
    if (val1.children.length > 0) {
        val1.children.forEach(val2 => {
            if (val2.propertyId) {
                leftMenuPropertyIds.push(val2.propertyId);
            }
        });
    }
});

console.log(leftMenuPropertyIds);
```

Comment: Can you add the data & required result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flatten `array` and `object`, using `reduce` method. reduce will help to remove unwanted node.

```js
const list = [
  {
    propertyId: "1",
    text: "1",
    children: [
      { propertyId: "2", text: "1", children: [] },
      { propertyId: "", text: "1", children: [] },
      { propertyId: "3", text: "1", children: [] }
    ]
  }
];

const flat = (v, arr) => {
  if (v.propertyId) arr.push(v.propertyId);
  (v.children || []).forEach(v2 => flat(v2, arr));
  return arr;
};
const rest = list.reduce((arr, item) => flat(item, arr), []);

console.log(rest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on compatibility, you could use `filter()`, `map()` and `flatMap()` on an array. Then using `...` to spread the results into a single array.

```
function getLeftMenuPropertyIds(): string[] {
  const leftMenuIds = this.leftMenuItems
    .filter(leftMenuItem => leftMenuItem.propertyId !== undefined)
    .map(letMenuItem => letMenuItem.propertyId);

  const leftMenuChildrenIds = this.leftMenuItems
    .flatMap(leftMenuItem => leftMenuItem.children)
    .filter(child => child.propertyId !== undefined)
    .map(child => child.propertyId);

  return [...leftMenuChildrenIds, ...leftMenuIds]
}
```